# Calculation bug in R

Tags: r, floor

I noticed, that the following check is giving **FALSE** in **R**:

```
(1000*0.6/24)==(1000*(0.6/24))

[1] FALSE
```

as follow up the **floor** function is giving different results:

```
floor(1000*0.6/24)
[1] 25

floor(1000*(0.6/24))
[1] 24
```

This inconsistency is critical for my code.

Does somebody have an explanation and a tip on how to prevent this behavior?

Thank you.

Best regards,

John

Comment: The purported duplicate does not answer the question of "how to prevent this behavior" in R.  I have re-opened it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a frequently asked question -- see [FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). It is due to the fact that floating point in R and all other computer languages has a finite number of digits of precision.  You can use all.equal.  Note that:

1. the numeric method of all.equal has a tolerance argument which defaults to sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) but can be set to other values.
2. all.equal returns TRUE if the two arguments are within the tolerance but does not return FALSE otherwise so we use isTRUE to ensure a logical result.

Thus

```
isTRUE(all.equal( (1000*0.6/24), (1000*(0.6/24)) ))
## [1] TRUE

isTRUE(all.equal(1, 2))
## [1] FALSE
```

You can also do it like this:

```
abs( (1000*0.6/24) - (1000*(0.6/24)) ) < sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
## [1] TRUE
```

or possibly just choose a value:

```
abs( (1000*0.6/24) - (1000*(0.6/24)) ) < 1e-8
## [1] TRUE
```

You may also want to look at https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/443/modeling-floor-function-exactly

Comment: Small correction: floating point *arithmetic* is 100% exact (unless using broken tools, such as the `-ffast-math` option on GCC). It’s just that fixed-size fractions fundamentally can’t represent all rational (let alone real) numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First lest look at the R documentation for this functions:

> S4 methods These are all (internally) S4 generic.
>
> ceiling, floor and trunc are members of the Math group generic. As an
> S4 generic, trunc has only one argument.
>
> round and signif are members of the Math2 group generic.
>
> Warning The realities of computer arithmetic can cause unexpected
> results, especially with floor and ceiling. For example, we ‘know’
> that floor(log(x, base = 8)) for x = 8 is 1, but 0 has been seen on an
> R platform. It is normally necessary to use a tolerance.

Now if you run the experiment using round, you go the following:

```
> floor(1000*(0.6/24))
[1] 24
> 
> floor(1000*0.6/24)
[1] 25
> 
> round(1000*(0.6/24))
[1] 25
> 
> round(1000*0.6/24)
[1] 25
> 
> ceiling(1000*(0.6/24))
[1] 25
> 
> ceiling(1000*0.6/24)
[1] 25
>
```

Conclusion: ceiling is working but as the documentation suggests, can also fail as floor. Round seems to be a better option here.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for your proposals.

My actual problem was that

```
floor(1000*(0.6/24))
[1] 24
```

The issue can be solved by dividing/multiplicating both sides with enough big number.

Example with **100**:

```
> floor(1000*100*(0.6/24/100))
[1] 25
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will consistently solve this problem for you

Comment: It does, you just need to use a big enough multiplicator.

Comment: That's not true. On my machine `floor(1000*100*(0.6/24)/100)` comes out at **25**, but `floor(1000*1000*(0.6/24)/1000)` comes out at **24**. Changing the equation changes the binary value, but not in the predictable way you assert here.